# Delete files contained in repeated directory locations

Tags: batch-file

I'm looking for a way to script a repeating deletion task. We have a standard directory template which is used repeatedly with the top level renamed. I want to target a named folder in all these directories to delete the files e.g.

```
wxyz\TemporaryFiles  
acbd\TemporaryFiles
```

etc. I have tried the following:

```
for /d %%i in (X:\Company\Projects\*) do cd TemporaryFiles && del /f /s /q %%i\*.*
```

I must have my syntax wrong and would appreciate some help - thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem in your code is that once the `cd` is executed, as it is not reverted, the rest of the `cd` operations are executed in a wrong place.

Try with

```dos
for /d %%i in ("X:\Company\Projects\*") do (
    pushd "%%~fi\TemporaryFiles" && (
        rmdir . /s /q
        popd
    )
)
```

That is, for each folder inside `Projects` folder, change current active directory to the folder found + subfolder `TemporaryFiles` and remove anything inside. Once done, revert the directory change and continue with the next folder

Answer (score 1):

Simpler:

```
for /d %%i in ("X:\Company\Projects\*") do del /f /s /q "%%i\TemporaryFiles\*.*"
```

If some directories have not the `TemporaryFiles` folder, then an error message is shown. You may supress such a message including `2>nul` part at end.